# Number of core registers in Cortex-M4? ARM's TRM says "32-registers" but diagrams show fewer

Tags: arm, embedded, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, cortex-m

so , I am a little bit confused right now
while reading **Cortex M4 technical reference Manual** , I came to this line in section 3.8 page 46 [stated here on arm website](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100166/0001/Programmers-Model/Processor-core-register-summary?lang=en):

> **Processor core register summary**
>
> The processor has 32-registers that includes 13 general-purpose registers and several special-purpose
> registers.

but When I counted them they were about 16 register not 32 according to Cortex M4 technical reference Manual.

on the other hand , while reading the **Cortex M4 generic user guide** , I come to this table where it shows around 23 register as in the image:
[image: a picture from generic user guide]

, please note that **PSR** register is in fact 3 register not one as I understood from the user guide , so where are the rest of the registers ?, as according to technical reference  manual , it's supposed that there are 32 core registers .

Comment: Where are you seeing this text - a link would be useful.  At https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Processor-core-register-summary it has different text than your quote, as does the PDF download from the same - still section 3.8 p46 (or p3-21).  SInce this is the r0p0 version of the document and there are no other versions currently, I think you have simply misread then misquoted the text.

Comment: @Clifford. no , actually I didn't misread it . I wasn't reading from the website , I downloaded the technical reference manual as a pdf ,Revision: r0p1 from arm website and when I came to the line in page 46 , it stated that as I mentioned in the question above , I actually copied the quoted line from the reference manual to sack overflow  as it is, I didn't even bother myself to write the line from scratch, but I get it , It seems like that happens to be some small mistakes or typos in the documentation.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  It is weird that ARM provide a "version" drop down that shows no version other than the one you are already looking at.  I am sure that was not always the case, and old documentation was previously marked as "superseded" too.  If you explicitly search for it, there is indeed an r0p1 - I missed that.  Weird also that they introduced an error by erroneously changing a line that was previously correct.  Apologies for doubting you, but also why you should also provide a link - so we are all looking at the same.

Comment: ... The r0p1 web-based documentation also has this error: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100166/0001/Programmers-Model/Processor-core-register-summary?lang=en.  My error was searching on "Processor core register summary" and that took me to r0p0 with no indication that an update exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a typo. The manual talks about "32-**bit** registers", not "32 registers".

> The processor has the following 32-bit registers:
>
> - 13 general-purpose registers, r0-r12
> - Stack Pointer (SP) alias of banked registers, SP_process and SP_main
> - Link Register (LR), r14
> - Program Counter (PC), r15
> - Special-purpose Program Status Registers, (xPSR).

See https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Processor-core-register-summary

Comment: But he is quoting the same source as your link, so the typo is only in this question, not the manual I think. Even the PDF version does not contain the text the OP has "quoted".

Comment: @Clifford: The OP's edit now has a link to the typoed version in HTML on ARM's web site.  (Oh, probably taken from your comments a few hours after you posted this one.  Thanks for tracking that down.)